# select_max not working in CI

Tags: codeigniter

This is not working in my CI app:

```
$query = $this->db->select_max('order')->get('posts');
print_r($query);
```

Why is that?

I have a column in my DB called `order` (int, where the highest value is currently 6) and the table is called `posts`

Why nothing is outputted instead a number 6 ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This just runs the query, you need to use `->row()` to get the result from it.

```
$this->db->select_max('order', 'max_order');
$query = $this->db->get('posts');

echo $query->row()->max_order;
```

DOCS:

- https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide2/database/active_record.html
- https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide2/database/results.html

Comment: thanks, the problem was in the word order. for some reason it needs to be used with 'max_order'as a second parameter.

Comment: @user2989475: It's because the 2nd param adds an alias: ``MAX(`order`) as `max_order` ``.  Without the 2nd param, you'd need to do: `$result = $query->row_array(); echo $result['MAX(order)'];`.